# Spring Boot Parent Version to use in SCDF Processor Modules

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

We are developing projects on SCDF with kafka release version 2.4.1 for dataflow and 2.3.1 for skipper. I have a cloud stream application which works fine when unit tested in my IDE. but when i register as processor, i do not see any activity on the logs for this specific app in my Stream.

Currently using Boot 2.2.5 with Hoxton.SR3.

But the app works fine when I go to spring boot version 2.1.4. The reason I went to spring boot 2.1.4 was that the sample apps on this URL use 2.1.4

So if there is a documentation to let know which spring boot versions to use for an SCDF release it would help.

Comment: The link for samples I was referring above.https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/blob/master/dataflow-website/stream-developer-guides/streams/standalone-stream-kafka/dist/usage-cost-stream-kafka.zip?raw=true

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Data Flow 2.4.1.RELEASES uses Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE.

To know which version of Spring Boot is used in SCDF, you can see the release notes of Spring Cloud Data Flow. For instance, 2.4.1.RELEASE info is [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/releases/tag/v2.4.1.RELEASE)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was not able to post the code hence created this question. Any help or direction is highly appreciated. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60856691/processor-app-in-spring-boot-2-2-4-hoxton-sr1-not-working-in-spring-cloud-data-f