# Processor App in Spring Boot 2.2.4/Hoxton.SR1 not working in Spring Cloud Data Flow 2.4.1

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to develop a new application to work on SCDF 2.4.1 and Skipper 2.3.1

I took the samples from 
https://github.com/sabbyanandan/stream-programming-models

I built them locally. Downloaded the docker compose for SCDF kafka, set the Versions and mount my repo and start my docker compose.

When I deploy the "function" module and create a simple stream
http | customUpper | log

I see the sample working fine and able to see log output as expected.

When I modify the function stream app, to use Spring Boot, 2.2.4 and Hoxton.SR1 for cloud stream dependencies. I do not see any output in the log.

BootApp

```
public class FunctionStreamSampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FunctionStreamSampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> uppercase() {

        return data -> {
            System.out.println("Input "+data);
            return data.toUpperCase();
        };
    }
}

application.yml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: uppercase

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <artifactId>function219</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>function219</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have removed the test classes just to strip it to bare minimum to avoid other dependency. The same app does work when deployed as is using the 2.1.4 version of spring boot it was originally built on.  Do let know if there are changes needed to be done to make it work on SCDF

When i use kafkatools to check the topics created by the stream, I see messages only in the streamname.http, but processor doesnt seem to be reading messages as my sysout is not getting printed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the current published stream apps, http and log, use an earlier version of spring-cloud-stream, based on spring boot 2.1.x. The newer version of spring-cloud-stream that is compatible with boot 2.2.x is not backwards compatible. All apps in the stream must be on the same (or compatible) spring-cloud-stream versions. I expect if you look at the log for custom processor, you will see some conversion error.

Comment: Sure, thanks will see if a custom source, sink works in this latest version. But at this time no, I do not see any log in stdout or stderr log files of processor. Last line is partition assigned... which is the last line after the stream is successfully deployed.

Comment: @dtruanski. I tried this, created a stream with source as a kafka queue > uCaseFunction > customSink i do not see any log statement in any of the modules, I removed processor and put in the customsink, still no log statement or no error statements in any of the modules. Modules are plain vanilla modules with just a simple uppercase function and a consumer <string>, but my offset is never increased in my kafka topic. If not 2.2.4/Hoxton.SR1, what is the minimum version which will work using the java.util.function paradigm. for processors and sinks

Comment: which helps in simplified Unit Testing without having to go thru messagecollectors and stuff

Answer (score 0):

For function based stream modules to work with SCDF, you need to add the appropriate binding name properties to `input` and `output` to your application properties as described here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_functional_binding_names

Essentially, this maps the functional binding endpoint names to the SCDF endpoint names, `input` and `output`.  For example, if you have a Function `foo':

`spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.foo-in-0=input`
`spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.foo-out-0=output`

.Future releases of the prepackaged stream modules will use the Functional paradigm and will provide these properties automatically.

Comment: Thanks for response. This resolved this function component. But the sink I built, using Function module as base. Changed return type of Bean to Consumer. In application yml mentioned function name and added only input binding. But my sink module is looking for function with name same as processor module. Got this message in log !!! Failed to discover function 'messenger' in function catalog. Function available in catalog are: [sample, functionRouter], when i change this name to messenger  in my sink app to match processor, it works fine. would be a big limitation to have same name for all

Comment: Added full details of the app currently  used in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030849/scdf-stream-processor-sink-apps-not-working-if-the-function-binding-names-arent